# Compress Size of Image taken by Custom Camera

Tags: android, bitmap, camera, compression, resolution

How to compress size of Image taken by ***Custom Camera***

*Getting* **3264 x 2448 pixels** *Image Resolution*

*Required* **1024 x 768 pixels** *Image Resolution*

I want whenever user take picture by using Custom Camera, it should be in ***Required size (1024 x 768 pixels)***

*Note:* On **Emulator** by default i am getting (**640 X 480 pixels**), while on **Device (3264 x 2448 pixels)**

**CameraActivity : -**

```
 private Camera mCamera;

    private PreviewSurface mCameraPreview;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

                 mCamera = getCameraInstance();

                    mCameraPreview = new PreviewSurface(this, mCamera);
                    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
                    preview.addView(mCameraPreview);

                    Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
                    Log.d(CameraLauncherActivity.LOG_TAG, "captureButton :: " + captureButton);
                    captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                            Log.d(CameraLauncherActivity.LOG_TAG, "mCamera.takePicture :: " + mCamera);                                         
                        }
                    });

    private Camera getCameraInstance() {

            Camera camera = null;
            Log.d(CameraLauncherActivity.LOG_TAG, "getCameraInstance()Camera:: " + camera);
            try {
                camera = Camera.open(0);
                Log.d(CameraLauncherActivity.LOG_TAG, "getCameraInstance()open:: " + camera);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // cannot get camera or does not exist
            }
            return camera;
        }
    }
```

---

**PreviewSurface.java:-**

```
public PreviewSurface(Context context, Camera camera) {
            super(context);
            this.mCamera = camera;

            this.mSurfaceHolder = this.getHolder();
            this.mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
            this.mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
            this.mSurfaceHolder.setFixedSize(100, 100);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // left blank for now
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format,
                int width, int height) {

                // start preview with new settings
                try {
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                // intentionally left blank for a test
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all preview sizes are supported by all cameras. You need to set the preview size of the camera to the closest possible to your target resolution.

Use `mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();` to get supported screen sizes and use:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
```

to set the preview size. You can compress the result image if you desire the exact size.

Update:

private Camera getCameraInstance() {

```
    Camera camera = null;
    Log.d(CameraLauncherActivity.LOG_TAG, "getCameraInstance()Camera:: " + camera);
    try {
        camera = Camera.open(0);
        Log.d(CameraLauncherActivity.LOG_TAG, "getCameraInstance()open:: " + camera);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // cannot get camera or does not exist
    }
    if(camera!=null){
     //get supported sizes:
     List<Size> localSizes = camera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
     //loop through localSizes to get closest size
     Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
     parameters.setPreviewSize(/*closest you could find*/);
     camera.setParameters(parameters);
    }
    return camera;
}
```

}

Comment: I believe you are right, where i need to use this in my code, see above i posted my PreviewSurface.java code

Comment: In your getCameraInstance() method before returning the Camera object

Comment: now too slow..., too big with this : parameters.setPreviewSize(1024, 768); getting New Image Size - 4608 x 2592

Comment: Does you camera support 1024x768? Try debugging and see the values in localSizes